# How to insert deleted rows in another table in sql

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two tables in my sample database. These are called:

1. Active Products.
2. Inactive Products

In my asp form I have two list boxes and a dropdown list.

DropDown List: Category.

When I select any one category like milk products in my dropdown list, it will show these products under list in the category on my Left side.

1. Products to Active. - [ Left Side ]
2. Activated Products. - [ Right side ]

I used to buttons for move the list items for move left and right side. When I click an update button, it will take the list items what contains on right side list box and insert these items in first table called `Active Products.`

Now I select two list items on my right side and I move them to left side list box and click update button, that moved items are updated in second table. How do I do this?

**Active** table:

```
Categoryid | Produtid
-----------+-----------     
   1            1   
   1            5
   1            6
```

Example if i select a first category, that corresponding products were display in right side, if i move `Productid 5 and 6` on left side.

It will be deleted in this table updated on in-active table.

My expected output will be look like this, how to wrote function for getting this output. someone please guide me. Thanks in advance,

**Active** table:

```
Categoryid | Produtid
-----------+---------
   1            1
```

**Inactive** table:

```
Categoryid | Produtid
-----------+----------
   1            5   
   1            6
```

Comment: I suggest that you instead create an `Inactive` flag on the product table, rather than duplicating the entire table

Comment: Your sample database is designed wrong. As Nick.McDermaid wrote, You should have a single table for product, with a bit column column indicating if the product is active or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inserting:

```
INSERT INTO InactiveTable
SELECT * FROM ActiveTable WHERE RowId = "<insert rowid>"
```

For deleting:

```
DELETE FROM ActiveTable
WHERE RowId = "<insert rowid>"
```

Obviously **insert before you delete**.

Answer (score 1):

First of, I'd suggest you use an Active/Inactive flag (just add a bit to your table).

If that's really not what you want, you can write an SQL-trigger. Should look something like this:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER dbo.SetActiveProductToInactive
    ON dbo.ActiveProducts
    FOR DELETE
AS
    INSERT INTO dbo.InactiveProducts
    SELECT * FROM deleted
GO
```

This inserts all deleted items into your ActiveProducst table before actually deleting them. If this is too much for what you are trying to accomplish, you should look at James' answer.

Answer (score 0):

when you delete row it returns record. Try this.

Creating new table:

`CREATE TABLE archived_table_timestamp AS WITH deleted_rows as
(DELETE FROM main_table RETURNING *)SELECT * FROM deleted_rows`;

to insert in existing table:

```
WITH deleted_rows as (
DELETE FROM active_table WHERE 'condition' RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO archived_table SELECT * FROM deleted_rows;
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@Nick.McDermaid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1690193/nick-mcdermaid) mentioned in the comments it would be better to have Inactive flag on the product table. But if you still need to move these rows between to tables you can use **OUTPUT** clause to do that just *in a single statement*.

First we are creating these to tables

```
create table #Active (Categoryid int, Productid int);
create table #Inactive (Categoryid int, Productid int);
```

Second we are inserting these records

```
insert into #Active (Categoryid, Productid) values (1, 1), (1, 5), (1, 6);
```

Third we are deleting some rows from #Active table and inserting them to the #Passive table

```
delete  t
output  deleted.*
into    #Inactive
from    #Active AS t
where   t.Productid in (5, 6);
```

If you need much more details about OUTPUT clause you can visit that link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql